# Magento 2 code sniffer showing session_id() warning

Tags: magento2, coding-standards, custom-extension

After running the code sniffer on Magento 2 extension got several warnings and that includes one warning saying "The use of function session_id() is discouraged". So what is the alternative to get the session_id in Magento 2 extension?

Comment: where you have used it?

Comment: @AmitBera want to use while posting data to the third party API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal is that you should be using Magento framework methods instead of php functions

For example

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/5a9fcab6a35b6b39e10f47ca1ea22dfca4b794a4/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Visitor.php#L178

```
            $this->setSessionId($this->session->getSessionId());
```

Comment: Great! Thanks man